# mapbox : how to combine two expressions to style a layer?

Tags: expression, mapbox-gl-js

I have this expressions that styles my layer when a feature is clicked:
the circle radius changes from 2 (default) to 5 (clicked).

```
'circle-radius'=> [
    'case',
    ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'clicked'], false],
    5,//clicked
    2//default
  ]
```

But I also want that the radius changes when the feature is hovered:

```
'circle-radius'=> [
    'case',
    ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hovered'], false],
    7,//hovered
    2//default
  ]
```

How can I combine those two expressions into one ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found out:

```
      'circle-radius'=>[
        'case',
        ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hovered'], false], 7,
        ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'clicked'], false], 5,
        2 //else
      ]
```